# Reusing views vs creating new views. Performance-wise

Tags: android

I have an application that lets you flip through cards in a deck.

Would it be better to reuse maybe 2-3 views(cards) and just change the text/image on them.

Or should i recreate(inflate) a new view(card) each time?

Performance wise which is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reusing is always better performance wise.  Think about it-  if you create new ones, you have to create these large objects, then set values to various properties.  If you reuse, you just set the values.  Creation is a superset of the work you do or reuse.  If you want to see the difference, create a relatively complex ListView.  Run it with full recycling.  Then run it where you create a new View for each getView call.  That performance difference is due to creation.

Now the question is if its enough of a bonus to be worth doing.  If the number of subviews is small enough, maybe not.  As the complexity of the views and the number of them increase, then it is.